# Understanding return function(x) from outer function(array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am learning JavaScript and got a bit confused with the following exercise. I did had to create a filter that would accept another functions as a sorting method. The thing that I cant understand a bit is how exactly the `for loop` passes the `value` to the `x`. Can you please explain?

```
function filter(arr, func) {

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        var value = arr[i];
        if (func(value)) {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }

    return result

}

function inBetween(a, b) {
    return function(x) {
        return a <= x && x <= b;
    }
}

function inArray(arr) {
    return function(x) {
        console.log(x)
        return arr.indexOf(x) != -1;
    }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

alert(filter(arr, function(a) {
  return a % 2 == 0
})); // 2,4,6

alert( filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)) ); // 3,4,5,6

alert( filter(arr, inArray([1, 2, 10])) ); // 1,2
```

Comment: In `if (func(value))` the value is passed to the function; `func(value)` is a function call. It's not super clear what it is you're asking, however.

Comment: @Pointy I am confused about that I do pass a function which has preset attributes for example inBetween(a,b), but at the same time in for loop it is func(value), so I dont get a little why this value goes to the inner-return function.

Comment: @Trincot has a nice explanation below. When a function returns another function, as in `inArray` or `inBetween`, that returned function "remembers" the context in which it was created. It's just an ordinary function, but it retains access to stuff from the environment where it was made, like the `arr` parameter. Otherwise it's no different from any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take this line as example:

```
filter(arr, inArray([1, 2, 10])) );
```

*inArray* is called with `arr = [1, 2, 10]`.

It returns the following (anonymous) function, for that particular *arr*:

```
function (x) {
    return arr.indexOf(x) != -1;
}
```

So the original line now can be pictured as:

```
filter(arr, function (x) {
    return [1, 2, 10].indexOf(x) != -1;
});
```

Now *filter* is called with *func* set to that anonymous function. The following code calls that function:

```
    if (func(value)) {
        result.push(value);
    }
```

So when this *func* is called, this really means the above anonymous function is called, and the parameter *x* gets set to *value* at the moment of the call. It is just like with any other function call, the parameters of the function get the values of the arguments in the actual call.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter function accepts the array to filter, and a function that does the filtering. In this part:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var value = arr[i];
    if (func(value)) { //here, you invoke the function on the array's values
        result.push(value);
    }
}
```

So if, for instance, we look at the `inBetween(3, 6)` function, which is this:

```
return function(x) {
    return 3 <= x && x <= 6;
}
```

(If you don't understand this part, read some more about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures))

So now that function is simply a function that accepts a value and returns true/false on whether or not it's between 3 & 6.

You eventually get an invocation on each of the array's values (1, 2, 3 ... 7) with the above function.

Same goes for all other functions you listed.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6))`

You are not "passing a function", but passing the **result from a function call**. The result is another (anonymous/unnamed) function.

From this line:

`function filter(arr, func) {`

We know name the function passed as an argument to `filter` is named `func`, then:

`if (func(value)) {`

executes this function.

In JavaScript, a function is just an object like other objects. To differentiate "function object reference" from "function calls", you can look for `()`.

`inBetween` is a function object reference, `inBetween(x, y)` means calling this function.

Anonymous functions can be defined, assigned to a variable, and passed as an argument as well. It may be executed instantly after definition as well:

```
function() {
  alert("called!");
}();
```

This may look exotic to people new to JavaScript though.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this explanations, but I still dont get one thing. I will show how I see the situation and if you have some time please correct me why I am wrong :)
https://fiddle.jshell.net/cdbs6ohm/1/ 
I expect that value will be added as the argument[2] to the called function arguments. And dont get how the x argument appears go the the lexical environment.

Comment: The fiddle you given has wrong syntax. You can edit it and use comments to point out the part which you do not understand, so I can try to better explain it.

Comment: I've added some comments into the code, the code is not working, what I really dont understand is the logic :) https://fiddle.jshell.net/cdbs6ohm/4/