# How are the parameters passed in this function?

Tags: javascript

Doing a text book exercise where:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function inBetween(a, b) {
  return function(x) {
    return x >= a && x <= b;
  };
}

alert( arr.filter(inBetween(3, 6)) ); // 3,4,5,6
```

The textbook also states that the `filter` syntax to be:

```
let results = arr.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  // should return true if the item passes the filter
});
```

So I'm not completely understanding how the `inBetween(a,b)` function works... like in this line:

```
arr.filter(inBetween(3,6))
```

It seems to me like `a` is the `item` parameter, `b` is in the `index` parameter, but obviously that's not how it's working... Can someone break down this syntax and why it's working?

Comment: `x` is the `item` parameter. `inBetween` returns a function which gets used for the filter.

Comment: `inBetween` is a *higher-order function*. It *returns a function* when called.

Comment: See also [Understanding return function(x) from outer function(array)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664970/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the filter method accepts a function that should return true or false, whether to keep the item or not.

In this example, instead of writing that function inside the filter, it's written outside and passed in. However you can still think about it like this:

```
let results = arr.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return item >= 3 && item <= 6;
});
```

The reason you would define `inBetween` outside the filter is so you can pass in values instead of hard coding them into the filter like above.

When you call `inBetween(3,6)` returned is :

```
function(x) {
    return x >= 3 && x <= 6;
}
```

Like above that's then put into the filter (just without the `index/array` parameter since they are not needed:

```
let results = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x >= 3 && x <= 6;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b`, `3`, `6` are defined in the scope of `inBetween` and referenced within the returned anonymous function which is the callback of `.filter()`, as indicated by [4castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720204/how-are-the-parameters-passed-in-this-function/46720229#comment80387095_46720204), `x` is `item` at the callback function